# including html tag in state of vuex

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex

I have some data that includes html tags in the state of vuex, but I want the html tags can be parsed as normal html tags, not to escape them. How can I achieve this task.
For example,

```
export default {
  state: {
    someHtml: '<a href="">This is a a tag.</a>'
  }
}
```

this.$store.state.someHtml can be displayed as a html link.

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of using Vue? You're supposed to store data, not HTML strings. You should leverage the virtual DOM to construct elements instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display unescapted HTML using Vue, use the `v-html` directive like so :

```
<div v-html="someHtml"></div>
```